# Why I'm getting error incompatible with the layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a cnn network, which I'm trying to test.
I'm getting errors about the input, and I can't figure why

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(99,13,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=4, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

where:

```
x_train / test .shape = {tuple: 3}(30, 99, 13)
y_train / test shape = {tuple: 1}30
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 99, 13]
```

What's  wrong and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(99,13,1)))
```

Model waiting for shape [batch, (99,13,1)], you are trying to feed [batch, 99, 13].
<strike>I think you need change your input to `input_shape=(99,13)` in order to match train data</strike>

Conv2D requires 4D+ [shape](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)
Expand dimension of your data to batch,99,13,1

Comment: I changed to input_shape=(99,13) and I got similar error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 99, 13]

Comment: Yep, should be 4d+ https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/